# Adding to Arraylists

Tags: java

i know how to add many things into arraylist at once, like:

```
String [] things = {"eggs ", "pie ", "lasers ", "hat "};
List list1 = new ArrayList();
```

for (String s: things)
    list1.add(s);

but is there a way to add things into arraylist iteratively one by one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ARE adding things iteratively, but if what you meant was the exact opposite

then if the elements are in any kind of Collection, you can use adAll(Collection c)
or if it's an array you can use Arrays.toList(...) to convert the array to a list that you can pass to adAll

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Similarly, you could use `List<String> list1 = Arrays.<String>asList(things);` to do it one one step rather than adding.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this:

```
List<String> thingsList = Arrays.asList(things);
```